# How to read the content of List in a View in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, strong-typing

So I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Agregar(int id)
        {
            Producto producto = db.Productos.Find(id);

            var list = new List<Carrito> { 
                new Carrito { ProductId = producto.ID, Cantidad = 1, PrecioUnitario = producto.Precio } 
            };

            return View(list);
        }
```

and I pass the variable `list` to the View, the problem is, I don't know how to access `ProductId` or `Cantidad`

Any idea how to do this?

Also, let's suppose the variable `list` has multiple objects, how to print the result of every object through a `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view (`Agregar.cshtml`) should be like this.

```
@model IEnumerable<Carrito>

<h2>We are gonna show the items in a loop now..</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.ProductId</p>
  <p>@item.Cantidad </p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I had to add <thenamespace.Models.carrito>

Comment: you can avoid it by adding "@using thenamespace.Models" at the top of the view.